# navbar-toggle works once then disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get a Bootstrap 3 based menu to work correctly. The issue is that it works fine once (opening and then closing the menu) via the navbar-toggle button but then the navbar-toggle symbol simply disappears.
I have done some research and the page first loads jquery.js and then bootstrap.js.
The menu includes a top navbar and a sidebar, the items of both are correctly inserted into the collapsed menu and toggling once works peachy. Toggling twice however is impossible due to the lacking button.

Here is the code in question:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-role="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" style="height:35px" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/home.png" class="img" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/yyv.png" alt="" class="img" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cxy.png" alt="" class="img" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/xxy.png" alt="" class="img" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="content_contact.php"><img src="images/kontakt.png" alt="Impressum" class="img" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li id="home" class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li id="manage-users"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Users</a></li>
            <li id="ges"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Lorem</a></li>
            <li id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-fw"></i> Ipsum <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="extra_content"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will get more success on an answer to your question if you provide a [minimal fully working code example that reproduces the bug](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it stands, your code needs a lot of work before it can actually be tested.

Comment: is this site live already?

Comment: Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/D8PtQ/1/ The first css lines are bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-theme.min.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some CSS that is overriding the default Bootstrap behavior (hiding the toggle button)...

```
.collapsed{
    display             : none;
    border              : 0;
}
```

Toggle button works once you remove it..

http://jsfiddle.net/kTyLg/